# __name__ attributes of actions defined in <class 'astromatchapp.report.admin.user.ReportUserAdmin'> must be unique

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
ERRORS:
<class 'astromatchapp.report.admin.user.ReportUserAdmin'>: (admin.E130) __name__ attributes of actions defined in <class 'astromatchapp.report.admin.user.ReportUserAdmin'> must be unique.
<class 'astromatchapp.web.admin.user.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E130) __name__ attributes of actions defined in <class 'astromatchapp.web.admin.user.UserAdmin'> must be unique.
?: (urls.E007) The custom handler404 view 'astromatchapp.web.views.http_error.handler404' does not take the correct number of arguments (request, exception).
```

After migrate to my manage.py this error has been generated.

Answer (score 5):

Seems this is broken in Django 2.2.

[Ticket 29917](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29917) discussed this (with mixed opinions) and although it is marked as fixed, the issue remains.

My observation shows that nothing is broken in actual functional code (actions do work and are not collected twice on inherited ModelAdmin classes). It's just that noisy warning that's trying to be too smart.

You can simply disable it by adding this to your settings:

`SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['admin.E130']`

Answer (score 2):

It's for new upgrade in django 2.2, you need to update actions, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#admin-actions-are-no-longer-collected-from-base-modeladmin-classes
This is the release note regarding the changes that causes this error.